# how to produce multiple rows into 1 column value or sql statement with comma seperated in T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-express

```
ColumnName  IsOrdered    Seq_ID
ABC          2              2
DEF          1              1
GHI          0             NULL
JKL          1              4
MNO          1              3
PQR          0              5
```

I have a table (table1) in the database with above values stored in it.

> Note: -

I. **Is_Ordered column**:  2 --> Desc; 1 --> Asc;  0 --> Default.

II. **Seq_ID column**:  Column names 'order by' sequence

These values are stored in the above table by user.(i.e. on User interface).  I want to produce a 'order by' clause from the multiple rows to a single statement with comma ',' seperated (one single column).

eg: select * from Table1 order by DEF asc, ABC desc, MNO asc, JKL asc

Here I want to write a sql statement to produce just the order by statement as above shown `i.e. (order by DEF asc, ABC desc, MNO asc, JKL asc)`

Here you will notice that GHI column and PQR columns are not included since these two are not selected in the order by selections in the user interface.

I thank you in advance who tried to understand my question and given an appropriate solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (may need to add a CAST)

```
SELECT
    'ORDER BY ' +
      SUBSTRING(
      (
      SELECT
          ',' + ColumnName + 
               CASE IsOrdered  
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'ASC'
                 WHEN 2 THEN 'DESC'
               END
      FROM
          MyTable
      WHERE
          IsOrdered > 0 -- why have "IsIncluded" column ?
      ORDER BY
          Seq_ID
      FOR XML PATH ('')
      )
      , 2, 7999)
```

Comment: Hi gbn,
Thank you for providing solution very quickly.
IsIncluded column I am actully using in report for condition to check if this value is 0 then to hide the column.
It is my bad, I just removed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
DECLARE @OrderBySetting VARCHAR(max) = ''
DECLARE @OrderByString VARCHAR(max) = ''

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR
FOR  SELECT  ColumnName + ' ' + 
case IsOrdered  
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ASC'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'DESC'
    END
    + ','
FROM         Table1
WHERE     (IsOrdered <> 0)
ORDER BY Seq_ID DESC

OPEN My_Cursor 

Fetch NEXT FROM MY_Cursor INTO @OrderBySetting

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @OrderByString = @OrderBySetting + @OrderByString


FETCH NEXT FROM MY_Cursor INTO @OrderBySetting
END
CLOSE MY_Cursor
DEALLOCATE MY_Cursor

SET @OrderByString = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY ' + SUBSTRING(@OrderByString, 1, LEN(@OrderByString)-1)
```

Comment: Hi Raymund, 
+1 for providing me very quick solution. Thanks!!!
As it is cursor based, looking with performance --- may be a bit slow.